# how to use rxjs / angular observable to publish a value

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I'm toying around with ionic (framework built on top of angular), and I am a bit puzzled around the Observable pattern from rxjs. I have the following situation:

- I want to make a service that holds a "real-time" updated counter, let's say unread messages.
- I want an outside influence to change the value, let's say one signal received message

I have something like the following code, but it goes wrong making the subscription in MyApp. I have a hard time finding how to publish new values from MyApp. I believe the normal procedure is to use the callback function when creating the Observable.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

```
@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

  numbers: Observable<number>;


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {  
    this.numbers = new Observable<number>();
  }

  get_n_messages()
  {
    return this.numbers;
  }  
}



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  subscription: any;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, oneSignal: OneSignal, dataCtrl: DataProvider) {    
    this.subscription = dataCtrl.get_n_messages().subscribe( x => {});
  }  

  private onPushReceived(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {
    alert('Push recevied:' + payload.body);
    this.subscription.next(666);1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `numbers` a `BehaviorSubject<number>` instead of an `Observable<number>`. BehaviorSubjects can be used both as an Observer and as an Observable.

So if you want to push new values to it, you can call the `next` method on it and pass the new value.

The listener/subscriber of this BehaviorSubject will get the new values.

So here are the changes that you'll have to do:

To your DataProvider

```
@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {    
  numbers$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);    
}
```

And to your component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  subscription: any;
  newNotificationCount;

  constructor(
    platform: Platform, 
    statusBar: StatusBar, 
    splashScreen: SplashScreen, 
    oneSignal: OneSignal, 
    dataCtrl: DataProvider
  ) {
    this.subscription = this.dataCtrl.numbers$.subscribe(newNotificationCount => this.newNotificationCount = newNotificationCount);
  }

  private onPushReceived(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {
    alert('Push recevied:' + payload.body);
    this.dataCtrl.numbers$.next(666);
  }
}
```

Although, since the value is being updated in the same controller, I don't really think such a DataProvider Service would be required. But if you want to show the notificationCount somewhere else as well and want to keep the count consistent throughout, then this would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

Use rxjs **Subject**

here's is an example

```
@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

  numbers: new Subject<number>();

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {  

  }

}
```

and in **.ts**

```
 @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {


     constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, oneSignal: OneSignal, dataCtrl: DataProvider) {  }

     private onPushReceived(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {
        alert('Push recevied:' + payload.body);

          this.dataCtrl.numbers.next(666);
      }

     ngOnInit() {

        this.dataCtrl.numbers.subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
     }


}
```